# In Ebay developer API, what is the difference between client credential grant flow and authorization code grant flow?

Tags: ebay-api

I want to make a OMS system.
And Using eBay API manage eBay order, I saw in the document, there are two types of authentication authorization mehtod, client credential grant flow and authorization code grant flow, respectively.
What is the different between two authorization method.
In my case, I want to build a system that input the user information to help the user manage their order and shipping, which authentication method should I use?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

You should learn how `OAuth` works.

In 2 words, `Oauth` with client credentials returns 2 `tokens`:  `auth_token` and `refresh_token`.

`auth_token` lasts for 2 hours only.

Then need to get a new one using `refresh_token`.

Then with a valid `auth_token` you call the `API` you want.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer, But I read the documentation and found that if use the client credentials the response look like   {
    "access_token": "v^1.1#i^1#p^1#r^0#I^3#f^0#t^H4s ... wu67e3xAhskz4DAAA",
    "expires_in": 7200,
    "token_type": "Application Access Token"
  }, the refresh token is contained in the response if you the authorization code grant flow. I  still confused with use of two type of grant mechanism.

Comment: In the document(https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-tokens.html), it said the client credential grant flow is use use to access the resources owned by the application, whereas the authorization code grant flow is use to access the resources owned by the user. I'm not sure what this mean by resource owned by something. Thank you.

Comment: In the page you linked it is explained the full flow. Make spme tests with both and see the response: it should clarify your doubts.